# Webpack css-loader and camelCase - How do I exclude a specific css file from being processed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, swiper.js, css-loader

I'm trying to exclude "swiper.min.css" to be excluded from processing as camelCase in my react webpack config but it keeps failing on other .css file when I do it like this.

I have tried many different options but each of them seems to lead nowhere :-(

I have tried with ternary operator, I have tried excluding based on wildcard etc - same result - it fails on all other .css files with this error:

"ERROR in ./src/pages/TimeTable/components/TimeTableLegend.module.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See [https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders"](https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders%22)

Any suggestion or pointers please?

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
    },
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "bundle.min.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /swiper\.min\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            modules: {
                                mode: (resourcePath) => {
                                    if (/common.css$/i.test(resourcePath)) {
                                        return 'global'
                                    }
                                    return 'local'
                                },
                                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:4]',
                                exportLocalsConvention: 'camelCase',
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    },
                ],
                test: /swiper\.min\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            modules: {
                                mode: (resourcePath) => {
                                    if (/common.css$/i.test(resourcePath)) {
                                        return 'global'
                                    }
                                    return 'local'
                                },
                                localIdentName: '[local]',
                                exportLocalsConvention: 'asIs',
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    },
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
};
```